# My question is related to remove function success, error, complete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery 3.x.x. As mentioned in jquery 3.x.x release note the method success, complete, error are removed. I am using success function with jquery 3.x.x ajax. My success function working fine instead of logging error in console. For reference
https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-special-case-deferred-methods-removed-from-jquery-ajax
My code is here:

```
<script src="jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#userName').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'JqueryTest',
            data : {
                userName : $('#userName').val()
            },
            success : function(responseText) {
                alert(responseText);
                $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(responseText);
            }
        });
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Finally success function works here, instead it should log error in console.

Comment: what do you want exactly?

Comment: Please describe more what is you question.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting confused between two different things which have the same name.

The [article](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-special-case-deferred-methods-removed-from-jquery-ajax) you linked to in the question says:

> Note that this does not have any impact at all on the ajax callbacks
>   of the same name passed through the options object, which continue to
>   exist and are not deprecated. This only affects the jqXHR methods.

When you write

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  success : function(responseText) {
  }
});
```

in your code, this is the callback specified through the `$.ajax()` options being referred to in the quote above. As the quote says, these options have not been removed or deprecated, and will continue to work. It's important to note that in this example `success` is the name of an *option*, not the name of a *function*. The function you supplied is anonymous.

The functions which have been removed are the those which belong to the jQuery `Deferred` object class - this is the type of object which is returned by `$ajax()`.

So for example if your code contained something like this:

```
var deferredResponse = $.ajax({ 
  url: "http://www.example.com",
  method: "GET"
});

deferredResponse.success(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

...then the "success" function there would no longer work in jQuery 3.0.

You can refer to https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ to see what options are currently valid to pass to `$.ajax()` and also to https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/ to see what methods are currently availble on the `Deferred` object.

Answer (score 0):

As of jQuery 3.0, `success`, `error` and `complete` has been removed and replaced with `done`, `fail` and `always`, like so:

```
$.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(function() {
    alert( "success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
  });
```

Comment: As of jQuery 3.0 success error and complete has been removed.but i am using success with jQuery 3.0.i am getting result properly.not error.but why.....

Comment: my question is this that success has been removed in jQuery 3.0.so should not use success with jQuery 3.0,but success i am doing already use with jQuery 3.0.why..?

Comment: the method `success()` has been removed, but the `setting` for `ajax()` called `success` is still available. More info: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/